# Organizing and Lifecycle management of S3 Objects

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am currently working on a script that does both the lifecycle management as well as Organizing of files.

We already have lifecycle management in place, the biggest limitation I found is, lifecycle management only changes the storage class while the files are in the same place where they where.

```
Example

aws s3api copy-object \
--copy-source s3://dshare/folderM/alia_b_2_3 \
--key alia_b_2_3 \
--bucket s3://dshare/folderIA/alia_b_2_3 \
--storage-class STANDARD_IA
```

I tried the above command, however I get regex error. Let me know if i'm doing anything wrong.

```
Error:
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "s3://dshare/folderIA/alia_b_2_3": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"
```

My idea basically is to copy/move the files into another folder under the same or different bucket and at the same time change the Storage Class Type for the files being copied/moved.

Answer (score 0):

`aws s3api copy-object` expects bucket name, not S3 URI starting with `s3://`, so in your case you need to only supply `dshare` as a value